# Abrir ventana modal antes de darle al botón de cerrar sesión

Tags: html, jquery, modal, sesiones

¿Cómo puedo hacer que salte un modal de **valoranos** cuando vayan a ir a cerrar sesión? Pero claro, que salga una única vez, hice una prueba pero sale siempre, y no me deja cerrar sesión.

Botón de cerrar sesión:

```
<li class="nav-item" style="width: 100%;">
    <a class="nav-link confirmation" href="logout.php" onMouseOver="$('#modal-valora').modal('show');">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt margsvg "></i> Cerrar Sesión
    </a>
</li>
```

El modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-valora" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <img src="images/logo/logo.svg" alt="DepilDiodo" class="logo-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-titulo" id="exampleModalLabel" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600; margin-left:20%;">¿Como valoras tu experiencia?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="boton-cerrar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <p class="clasificacion center" style="margin-top: -12px; margin-bottom: 3%;">
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
            <label for="radio1">★</label>
            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
            <label for="radio2">★</label>
            <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
            <label for="radio3">★</label>
            <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
            <label for="radio4">★</label>
            <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
            <label for="radio5">★</label>
          </p>
          <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="3" style="width: 100%;font-size: 13px;" placeholder="Recomiendanos ¿Estás contento/a con el servicio?"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnen pull-right" style="border-radius: 25px; float: right;">Enviar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btclos pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="border-radius: 25px; float: right;">Cerrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="pmoda" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Todos los datos están protegidos de forma <br>segura (HTTP/SSL)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Comment: onMouseOver="if (!modalMostrado) { $('#modal-valora').modal('show'); modalMostrado = true; } "

Comment: Si también lo pensé, pero la idea es que salga una sola vez. Es decir hacen clic en cerrar sesión y les salta un modal de valoranos, si no quieren hacerlo o bien lo hagan ese modal se cerrara, pero si vuelviera ir a cerrar sesión se les volvera a abrir el modal en lugar de cerrar sesión

Comment: No me queda claro. ¿Quieres que se abra el modal cada vez que vayan a cerrar sesión pero solo una vez por sesión o quieres que solo se les abra la primera vez que cierran sesión y ya nunca más?

Comment: Que se abra siempre hasta que ese usuario deje una valoración, también se podría? Es decir podemos abrir una tabla en la BD de valoraciones asociadas al id de Usuarios, podemos comprobar si ese usuario a dejado valoración y si no a dejado si le salte el modal, pero claro si no valoran que si puedan cerrar sesión

Comment: Claro que puedes pero entonces ya tienes que guardarte en base de datos que ese usuario ya ha hecho una valoración, aunque todo se complica más. Para lo que te interesa ahora, con tener una variable que indique si se ha mostrado el modal ya (como la que te he propuesto) sería suficiente ya que esa variable cambiaría de valor al mostrar el modal

Comment: Tienes razón quizás es complicarse mucho, probe lo que me pusiste pero no funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82956/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-miguel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saca el código que controla el evento `onMouseOver` a una función que declares en alguna sección de `script` o fichero de *JavaScript* que importes. Además, declaras una variable que controle si se ha mostrado ya el modal y pones un condicional que compruebe el valor de dicha variable para ver si se muestra o no.

Así quedaría en una sección de `script`, por ejemplo:

```
<script> 
    var modalMostrado = false; 
    function showModalValoracion() { 
        if (!modalMostrado) { 
            $('#modal-valora').modal('show'); 
            modalMostrado = true; 
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Y así la parte del evento:

```
onMouseOver="showModalValoracion();"
```